# How to set a rest api endpoint as Storm spout?

Tags: rest, apache-storm

I would like to setup a rest api endpoint as a storm spout i.e. whenever a request is made to the endpoint url (for ex. http://example.com/search?q=test) then I would like to execute a storm topology with certain bolts.

The problem is that not all the time requests are made also, the spout's `nextTuple()` method should be called at a certain interval of time and there is no idea whatsoever about this interval. And how could I also listen to a http url for request and execute the topology whenever a request is made? How to control concurrent requests and how could I determine the no. of workers to execute the topology because traffic to that url is uncertain.

One alternative workaround, is I thought of pushing the requests to the kafka queue as and when a request is made and then using the kafka spout. Any other idea on doing this without using kafka?

I need to do two jobs: process the request into json format and then produce the json string to kafka queue. Is storm a better solution for this?

Do I have to consider an alternative framework like Spark to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to have a look at [Storm DRPC](https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Distributed-RPC.html). In easy words, Storm DRPC is like a function, you provide params and you will get a result. Your Storm topology will be utilised to provide the answer.

Let your REST endpoint send the request to Storm DRCP.

Comment: Could you give me a code snippet or an example? Thank you.

Comment: @JavaTechnical I provided a link.

Comment: Also, will there be any loss of data? Using which protocol the client and the DRPC communicate? Does the DRPC server store requests for a configurable period of time?

Comment: @JavaTechnical Again, read Storm documentation. Once you read and something isn't clear, feel free to ask again.

Comment: Could you tell me which protocol does the client uses to communicate with DRPC. I didn't find it.

Comment: @JavaTechnical It is Apache Thrift.

Comment: I need to do two jobs: process the request into json format and then produce it to kafka queue. Is storm a better solution for this?

Comment: Do I understand from your last comment that your goal is to take send a rest API and send it to Kafka? Do the [Kafka HTTP Rest clients](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Clients#Clients-HTTPREST) not work for your use case?

Comment: DRPC is blocking call, we can't use it to send request !!! drpc wait till it get reply from storm's last bolt.

Comment: @kartik Ok. By "we" you mean JavaTechnical and you?

Comment: @Chiron, https://storm.apache.org/javadoc/apidocs/backtype/storm/drpc/LinearDRPCTopologyBuilder.html is deprecated, what should be used? Thanks!